# JavaL Make variable x automatically update to an operation (y+z)

Tags: java

I have a program in which I have the variable "attackTotal" (or x) to always be "attack (y) + weapon.getAttack() (z)".  I've come across the problem in which I need to update attackTotal (x) before I use it in case I  changed either attack (y) or weapon.attack (z) beforehand.  Is something like this possible?:

```
int x, y = 5, z = 7;
x (always)= y + z   // x is now 12
y += 2;   // y is now 7, x is now 14
```

Comment: (1) use a method called `updateAttackTotal` which evaluates `x = y+z` and call is every time y or z is updated. OR (2) update before actually accessing x.... I would prefer (2).

Comment: Replace access to `x` with a method, e.g. `getAttackTotal`, which calculates it from the current values of `y` and `z`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this approach for example :)

```
void incY(int by) {
     y += by;
     x = y + z;
}
```

or even

```
int getX() {
    return y + z;
}
```

Comment: I ended up scrapping x as a variable and now only use the getX() method, since that was basically its only function.